# Azure AD B2C - Custom UI for resetpassword.html

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I would like to disable or modify the regex check for the username in the custom "forgot your password" page in B2C.  I am using the standard template resetpassword.html ... I have usernames that begins with an underscore in my web application

I am getting the following validation message when trying to change the password for users with usernames beginning with an underscore

"The username you provided is not valid. It must begin with an alphabet or number and can contain alphabets, numbers and the following symbols: _ -"

For all other usernames that does not begin with an underscore, I have no issues resetting the password via the custom resetpassword.html page.

BTW my password reset policy's custom UI for forgot password points to this resetpassword.html

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default behavior with custom policies. Please check the azure documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom)